# MySql replication from 5.1 master to 5.6 slave keep crashing

Tags: mysql, replication, crash

I recently updated one of the replication slaves to mysql 5.6. 
After importing a recent dump from the master, I run mysql_upgrade  with no errors.

the database deamon started correctly with no error.

the problem began when I tried to start the slave;  the slave's engine crashed almost immediately,  in went on to a crash/restart endless loop.

this is what I've tried already

- upgrade the slave from 5.1 to 5.5  (had no problems with replication at 5.5)   and then up to 5.6 (crash)
- change both master and slave binary log to row format (*binlog-format=ROW* in the config file)
- resting both master and slave

my configuration is

- both serves are hosted on  a virtual machine (one for each)
- running CentOS 6.5
- the VM has 4 cpu's  and 8 GB of ram

Here is the log dump:

> 2014-11-13 14:03:07 1022 [Note] Slave I/O thread: connected to master
>   'replicator@10.209.1.147:3306',replication started in log
>   'mysql-bin.000069' at position 31248706
>  2014-11-13 14:03:07 1022
>   [Warning] Slave SQL: If a crash happens this configuration does not
>   guarantee that the relay log info will be consistent, Error_code:
>   0
>  2014-11-13 14:03:07 1022 [Note] Slave SQL thread initialized,
>   starting replication in log 'mysql-bin.000069' at position 3940, relay
>   log '/data/relay-bin.000003' position: 4103
>  2014-11-13 14:03:07
>   1022 [Warning] Slave I/O: Notifying master by SET
>   @master_binlog_checksum= @@global.binlog_checksum failed with error:
>   Unknown system variable 'binlog_checksum', Error_code: 1193
>   2014-11-13 14:03:07 1022 [Warning] Slave I/O: Unknown system variable
>   'SERVER_UUID' on master. A probable cause is that the variable is not
>   supported on the master (version: 5.1.71-log), even though it is on
>   the slave (version: 5.6.21-log), Error_code: 1193
>  2014-11-13
>   14:03:07 1022 [ERROR] Error reading packet from server: Could not find
>   first log file name in binary log index file ( server_errno=1236)
>   2014-11-13 14:03:07 1022 [ERROR] Slave I/O: Got fatal error 1236 from
>   master when reading data from binary log: 'Could not find first log
>   file name in binary log index file', Error_code: 1236
>  2014-11-13
>   14:03:07 1022 [Note] Slave I/O thread exiting, read up to log
>   'mysql-bin.000069', position 31248706
>  2014-11-13 14:03:07 1022
>   [ERROR] Slave SQL: Could not execute Write_rows_v1 event on table
>   tpportal.player_game_plays; Duplicate entry '5890402' for key
>   'PRIMARY', Error_code: 1062; handler error HA_ERR_FOUND_DUPP_KEY; the
>   event's master log mysql-bin.000069, end_log_pos 5048, Error_code:
>   1062
>  2014-11-13 14:03:07 1022 [Warning] Slave: Duplicate entry
>   '5890402' for key 'PRIMARY' Error_code: 1062
>  2014-11-13 14:03:07
>   1022 [ERROR] Error running query, slave SQL thread aborted. Fix the
>   problem, and restart the slave SQL thread with "SLAVE START". We
>   stopped at log 'mysql-bin.000069' position 3940
>  14:03:07 UTC -
>   mysqld got signal 11 ;
>  This could be because you hit a bug. It is
>   also possible that this binary
>  or one of the libraries it was
>   linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
>  or misconfigured.
>   This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
>  We will
>   try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
>   diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed,
>  something
>   is definitely wrong and this may fail.
>  
>   key_buffer_size=8388608
>  read_buffer_size=131072
>   max_used_connections=1
>  max_threads=100
>  thread_count=2
>   connection_count=1

It is possible that mysqld could use up to

> key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads =
>   47962 K  bytes of memory

Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

> Thread pointer: 0x7fc53c000990
>  Attempting backtrace. You can use
>   the following information to find out
>  where mysqld died. If you
>   see no messages after this, something went
>  terribly wrong...
>   stack_bottom = 7fc547ffe7e0 thread_stack 0x40000
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x35)[0x8dbbb5]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x494)[0x665f24]
>   /lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0xf710)[0x7fc695957710]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z10free_blobsP5TABLE+0x13)[0x76c103]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN14Relay_log_info20clear_tables_to_lockEv+0x31)[0x8b5e91]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN14Relay_log_info15cleanup_contextEP3THDb+0x84)[0x8b6064]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_slave_sql+0x1e6)[0x8b1ea6]
>   /usr/sbin/mysqld(pfs_spawn_thread+0x12a)[0xb00b1a]
>   /lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0x79d1)[0x7fc69594f9d1]
>   /lib64/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d)[0x7fc6946a0b6d]
>  
>  Trying to get
>   some variables.
>  Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to
>   abort.
>  Query (0): is an invalid pointer
>  Connection ID (thread
>   ID): 4
>  Status: NOT_KILLED
>  
>  The manual page at
>   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
>   information that should help you find out what is causing the
>   crash.
>  141113 14:03:07 mysqld_safe Number of processes running
>   now: 0
>  141113 14:03:07 mysqld_safe mysqld restarted
>  2014-11-13
>   14:03:08 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is
>   deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option
>   (see documentation for more details).
>  2014-11-13 14:03:08 1091
>   [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
>  2014-11-13 14:03:08 1091
>   [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
>   2014-11-13 14:03:08 1091 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is
>   disabled
>  2014-11-13 14:03:08 1091 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and
>   rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
>  2014-11-13 14:03:08 1091 [Note]
>   InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
>  2014-11-13 14:03:08 1091 [Note]
>   InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
>  2014-11-13 14:03:08 1091
>   [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
>  2014-11-13 14:03:08 1091
>   [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
>  2014-11-13 14:03:08
>   1091 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 4.0G
>   2014-11-13 14:03:08 1091 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of
>   buffer pool
>  2014-11-13 14:03:08 1091 [Note] InnoDB: Highest
>   supported file format is Barracuda.
>  2014-11-13 14:03:08 1091
>   [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 115242901774 and 115242901774
>   in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 115242901784 in
>   the ib_logfiles!
>  2014-11-13 14:03:08 1091 [Note] InnoDB: Database
>   was not shutdown normally!
>  2014-11-13 14:03:08 1091 [Note] InnoDB:
>   Starting crash recovery.
>  2014-11-13 14:03:08 1091 [Note] InnoDB:
>   Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
>  2014-11-13
>   14:03:08 1091 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data
>   pages
>  2014-11-13 14:03:08 1091 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite
>   buffer...
>  InnoDB: Last MySQL binlog file position 0 1405, file
>   name mysql-bin.000010
>  2014-11-13 14:03:09 1091 [Note] InnoDB: 128
>   rollback segment(s) are active.
>  2014-11-13 14:03:09 1091 [Note]
>   InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
>  2014-11-13 14:03:09 1091 [Note]
>   InnoDB: 5.6.21 started; log sequence number 115242901784
>   2014-11-13 14:03:09 1091 [Note] Recovering after a crash using
>   /data/mysql-bin
>  2014-11-13 14:03:09 1091 [Note] Starting crash
>   recovery...
>  2014-11-13 14:03:09 1091 [Note] Crash recovery
>   finished.
>  2014-11-13 14:03:09 1091 [Note] Server hostname
>   (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306

Answer (score 1):

Your master is not compatible with the 5.6 slave. `binlog_checksum` is only available on 5.6, and so is UUID. I have successfully replicated servers between 5.5 and 5.6. Perhaps you can check if these options can be disabled.

> 2014-11-13 14:03:07 1022 [Warning] Slave I/O: Notifying master by SET
>   @master_binlog_checksum= @@global.binlog_checksum failed with error:
>   Unknown system variable 'binlog_checksum', Error_code: 1193 2014-11-13
>   14:03:07 1022 [Warning] Slave I/O: Unknown system variable
>   'SERVER_UUID' on master. A probable cause is that the variable is not
>   supported on the master (version: 5.1.71-log), even though it is on
>   the slave (version: 5.6.21-log), Error_code: 1193

Comment: Thanks for your reply,  I found this blog post http://mechanics.flite.com/blog/2014/04/29/disabling-binlog-checksum-for-mysql-5-dot-5-slash-5-dot-6-master-master-replication/ ,  showing how to disable binlog_checksum.  how can I disable SERVER_UUID?

Comment: I'm not sure if disabling GTID mode does the trick, but here's ref doc for enable/disabling GTID http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-options-gtids.html#option_mysqld_gtid-mode

Answer (score 0):

The reason Manny Calaverra was able to replicate from 5.5 to 5.6, but you are not able to replicate from 5.1 to 5.6 is because of versioning support as listed in the documentation for MySQL. The dev team only retains complete backward master/slave compatibility between the current version of MySQL, and the most recent minor version. So if there are no effective workarounds out there, it is because that is a feature that simply is not supported by the database application.

Source: [Replication Compatibility Between MySQL Versions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-replication-excerpt/5.7/en/replication-compatibility.html)

> MySQL supports replication from one release series to the next higher release series. For example, you can replicate from a source running MySQL 5.6 to a replica running MySQL 5.7, from a source running MySQL 5.7 to a replica running MySQL 8.0, and so on. However, you may encounter difficulties when replicating from an older source to a newer replica if the source uses statements or relies on behavior no longer supported in the version of MySQL used on the replica. For example, foreign key names longer than 64 characters are no longer supported from MySQL 8.0.

If you can do it, one method that has been done was to create a middleman server. I have seen postings where people described successfully creating (specifically) a MySQL 5.1 server replicating to a MySQL 5.5 server then to a MySQL 5.6 server.